# line break in twitter

Tags: javascript, url

I wanna make the button to the tweet page and designate what text and what url and hashtags to tweet,
I want to tweet with the line break

`

```
const sendText = "aa \n"
const sendURL = window.location.href;
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + sendText + "&url=" + sendURL + "&hashtags=a,b");
```

`

I tried \n and br tag and [br /] but twitter still ignores me

Comment: You need to URL-encode your text, so \n becomes %0A - try `encodeURIComponent(sendText)`.

Comment: Instead of concatenating query parameters manually, please use the [`URL` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) and its `searchParams` property, which _correctly encodes_ parameters: `const url = new URL("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"); url.searchParams.set("text", sendText); url.searchParams.set("url", sendURL); url.searchParams.set("hashtags", "a,b"); window.open(url);`.